# Android caching network response for certain time limit

Tags: android, sqlite, caching, sharedpreferences, android-lru-cache

I am currently using HttpClient to perform a network request which returns a JSON object. I would like to cache the data that comes back and set an expiration of ten minutes to that cached data.

I have looked into using LruCache, SQLite, and shared preferences. Which would be the best way to perform this task? I am currently using an SQLite database for other parts of my app, so I was just thinking about using that and comparing the timestamp when the data was cached. That option will work for me, but seems like overkill since there will always only be one row in that table.

Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

shared preferences is simple and enough for you.